# Parsing array of data and sending with nodemailer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, nodemailer

I've got an array of data that I want to send in a table using `NodeMailer` that looks something like:

```
var results = [ { 
    asin: 'B01571L1Z4',
    url: 'domain.com',
    favourite: false,
    createdAt: 2016-11-18T19:08:41.662Z,
    updatedAt: 2016-11-18T19:08:41.662Z,
    id: '582f51b94581a7f21a884f40' 
  },
  { 
    asin: 'B01IM0K0R2',
    url: 'domain2.com',
    favourite: false,
    createdAt: 2016-11-16T17:56:21.696Z,
    updatedAt: 2016-11-16T17:56:21.696Z,
    id: 'B01IM0K0R2' 
   }]
```

What I am trying to do i to create a loop inside my HTML and then loop through the data.  I did try the below, but it seems there are limitations on what I can do.

```
  var sendUpdatedMerch = transporter.templateSender({
      from: '"Test" <domain1@gmail.com>', // sender address
      subject: 'Test Updates', // Subject line
      html: '<div><table><thead><tr><th>ASIN</th><th>Url</th><th>Favourite</th><th>createdAt</th></tr></thead><tbody>{{result.forEach((item) => {<tr><td>{{asin}}</a></td><td>{{url}</td><td>{{favourite}}</td><td>{{createdAt}}</td></tr>})}}</tbody></table></div>' // html body
  });

  sendUpdatedMerch({
    to: 'domain@gmail.com'
  }, {results}, function(err, info){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Done');
    }
  })
```

Could anyone point out where I am going wrong please and what I need to do to correct my problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you have tried to use `results.forEach((item)` but you placed this inside the quotes `'result.forEach((item)'` which is a string and won't execute at all.

You may have used this kind of syntax in your page when you used the view engines like `jade`, `swig` etc which will do the parsing for you. But here, you should call them manually to parse this kind of syntax.

Otherwise, you can do the parsing with the array function as below where I have used `array.reduce` which is handy and will do the parsing nicely.

You can try the same to generate the `content` and append it to the html as below.

```
    html: '<div><table><thead><tr><th>ASIN</th><th>Url</th><th>Favourite</th><th>createdAt</th></tr></thead><tbody>' + 
content + '</tbody></table></div>' // html body
```

```js
var results = [ { 
    asin: 'B01571L1Z4',
    url: 'domain.com',
    favourite: false,
    createdAt: '2016-11-18T19:08:41.662Z',
    updatedAt: '2016-11-18T19:08:41.662Z',
    id: '582f51b94581a7f21a884f40' 
  },
  { 
    asin: 'B01IM0K0R2',
    url: 'domain2.com',
    favourite: false,
    createdAt: '2016-11-16T17:56:21.696Z',
    updatedAt: '2016-11-16T17:56:21.696Z',
    id: 'B01IM0K0R2' 
   }];

var content = results.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + '<tr><td>' + b.asin + '</a></td><td>' + b.url + '</td><td>' + b.favourite + '</td><td>' + b.reatedAt + '</td></tr>';
}, '');

console.log(content);

/*
var sendUpdatedMerch = transporter.templateSender({
      from: '"Test" <domain1@gmail.com>', // sender address
      subject: 'Test Updates', // Subject line
      html: '<div><table><thead><tr><th>ASIN</th><th>Url</th><th>Favourite</th><th>createdAt</th></tr></thead><tbody>' + content + '</tbody></table></div>' // html body
  });


  sendUpdatedMerch({
    to: 'domain@gmail.com'
  }, {results}, function(err, info){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Done');
    }
  })
  
  */
```

Comment: Ahhh of course, I'm not using a template!  That works great.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful

Comment: what is 'a' parameter for in the function?

Comment: At first iteration, `a` is the seed value which was passed as empty string in the second argument of reduce function. On subsequent iterations, `a` is the previous iteration result.