# Insert array items in nodemailer html body

Tags: html, arrays, nodemailer

I am sending mail with nodemailer containing HTML as a mail body. I need to loop through an array and put array items in the HTML as a list. I tried the forEach method and for loop but all in vain.

***ARRAY***

```
[
  "1 ABC 1",
  "2 XYZ 1",
  "3 ZXC 1",
  "4 RYT 1",
]
```

***NODEMAILER CODE***

```
var mailOptions = {
        from: '<xyz@gmail.com>',
        to: email,
        subject: 'Your order has been placed successfully.',
        html:`<h2>Your order confirmation is below</h2>
              <li>${arrayItems},</li>`
      };
```

I need to display all the array elements in the li tag shown above. The reason I am using the HTML variable instead of a new file is that when I place HTML code in a different file, Gmail rejects the mail and the receiver didn't receive it. I tried to put script tags in this HTML variable and it returns undefined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing array of data and sending with nodemailer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956866/parsing-array-of-data-and-sending-with-nodemailer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this below sample to generate the list as text and embed in your html body.

```js
var list = [
  "ABC 1",
  "XYZ 1",
  "ZXC 1",
  "RYT 1",
];

var arrayItems = "";
var n;
for (n in list) {
  arrayItems += "<li>" + list[n] + "</li>";
}

var mailOptions = {
  from: '<xyz@gmail.com>',
  to: 'email',
  subject: 'Your order has been placed successfully.',
  html: `<h2>Your order confirmation is below</h2>
              <ul>${arrayItems},</ul>`
};

console.log(mailOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks, it serves my purpose. I was messing with this from the last 4 hours.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh this is a basic and simple code which achieve your purpose. happy to help. cheers buddy. :)